# PIVOT IN clause value as a variable

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Can you help me to solve this error. Everything works fine, but i am struck with pivot IN clause, where i want to pass values by using a variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Sample
(
  INPUT_TABLE_ID IN NUMBER,OUTPUT_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
  AGG_COLUMNS VARCHAR2(2000);

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COLUMNS FROM COLUMN_NAMES' INTO AGG_COLUMNS;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE      
      'CREATE TABLE '||OUTPUT_TABLE||' AS
      (
          SELECT *
          FROM BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN
          PIVOT
          (
            MAX(STRING_VALUE)
            FOR COLUMN_NAME  IN ( '||AGG_COLUMNS ||')
          )
      )';
```

And the error is:

```
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd either have to encode the values in the `COLUMN_NAMES` table like:

```
SQL> create table  COLUMN_NAMES(COLUMNS  varchar2(20));

Table created.


SQL> insert into column_names values ('''A'',''B''');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> create table  BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN(column_name  varchar2(15),
  2                                        string_value  varchar2(15));

Table created.

SQL> insert into   BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN values ('A', 'test');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into   BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN values ('B', 'pickle');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into   BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN values ('C', 'foo');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Sample
  2  (
  3    INPUT_TABLE_ID IN NUMBER,OUTPUT_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
  4  )
  5  IS
  6    AGG_COLUMNS VARCHAR2(2000);
  7  begin
  8   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COLUMNS FROM COLUMN_NAMES' INTO AGG_COLUMNS;
  9   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
 10        'CREATE TABLE '||OUTPUT_TABLE||' AS
 11        (
 12            SELECT *
 13            FROM BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN
 14            PIVOT
 15            (
 16              MAX(STRING_VALUE)
 17              FOR COLUMN_NAME  IN ( '||AGG_COLUMNS ||')
 18            )
 19        )';
 20  end;
 21  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec Sample(1, 'TEST');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

'A'             'B'
--------------- ---------------
test            pickle
```

or do it in the proc:

```
SQL> insert into column_names values ('A,B');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> create table  BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN(column_name  varchar2(15),
  2                                        string_value  varchar2(15));

Table created.

SQL> insert into   BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN values ('A', 'test');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into   BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN values ('B', 'pickle');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into   BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN values ('C', 'foo');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> commit;

...

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Sample
  2  (
  3    INPUT_TABLE_ID IN NUMBER,OUTPUT_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
  4  )
  5  IS
  6    AGG_COLUMNS VARCHAR2(2000);
  7  begin
  8   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COLUMNS FROM COLUMN_NAMES' INTO AGG_COLUMNS;
  9   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
 10        'CREATE TABLE '||OUTPUT_TABLE||' AS
 11        (
 12            SELECT *
 13            FROM BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN
 14            PIVOT
 15            (
 16              MAX(STRING_VALUE)
 17              FOR COLUMN_NAME  IN ( '''||replace(AGG_COLUMNS, ',', ''',''') ||''')
 18            )
 19        )';
 20  end;
 21  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec Sample(1, 'TEST');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

'A'             'B'
--------------- ---------------
test            pickle
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `AGG_COLUMNS` should correspond to the following format:

```
Value1 as ColumnName1, Value2 as ColumnName2, ...
```

Comment: The variable "AGG_COLUMNS" will contain comma separated values.

Comment: Is it possible to give a variable in PIVOT IN clause which contains a comma separated values.

Comment: @user1990383 - If `AGG_COLUMNS` contains list of comma-separated string values, then these strings must be enclosed in single quotes like `'val1', 'val2', ...`.  ColumnNames are optional.

Comment: Actually, the requirement is to find the comma separated values dynamically... After, then i need to pivot by passing AGG_COLUMNS variable.

Comment: @user1990383 - Just display dynamic SQL before executing it.  You will see if your list is correctly formed.

Comment: yah i checked that, its perfect... but the problem with IN clause itself... i want to know that is that possible to give a variable in IN clause ?

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'CREATE TABLE COLUMN_NAMES AS (
      SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS COLUMNS
      FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME
      FROM   BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN))';

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COLUMNS FROM COLUMN_NAMES' INTO AGG_COLUMNS;

Comment: when i execute the procedure im getting the following error.....................ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values

Comment: @user1990383 - Variables in pivot are not allowed.  Only constant expressions, as Oracle docs says.

Comment: @DazzaL gave me a solution to solve this problem.... Thank you so much for your valuable time...